# Duplicate question with better documented answers

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicates

Recently [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76906/22632) question has been rightfully closed as a duplicate. However, I feel that some of the answers on the duplicating question are better documented than on the duplicated one.

What is the best course of action in this case? Should the users move their answers to the original question? Given that the original already has an accepted answer and is quite old, I'm not sure how much visibility and votes they would attract.

Answer (score 7):

There are several options here.

The cleanest might be to reverse the flow on the duplicate closure. If the answers in the new question are better, then this is a definite option. Normal users *can* do this though it may be easier with a moderator.

If they are *exact* duplicates (not the case here). They can be merged and the answers from the new question can be moved via the merge to the old question.

Lastly, there is the option of having the users move their answers. This is less than ideal, but does not require any major intervention.

And final finally, you can totally just write a *best* answer on the original question that integrates the better sources and answers the question better than the old answers.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be reluctant to reverse the close and close a general case in favor of one specific implementation of it.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. Probably our better bet is the last last. A good well referenced new answer to the general case

Comment: Note: depending on how much the "best" answer borrows from others; a few acknowledgments might not be amiss. Attributions and all that...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Acknowledgements of ideas is polite; attributions are a different kettle of fish and are for when you use someone else's literal words.

Comment: @wax eagle: If you could address the issue of whether the new answer would get any traction, I feel i could accept this.

Comment: @Olorin I'm not quite sure what you're concern is here. It's a fairly typical practice to add a new, better (or new information providing) answer to an old question. Sometimes they get a lot of votes, sometimes they don't get many. If the answer is substantially better, it will likely garner some votes. Also the OP is notified when a new answer arrives and if they like it better they can change the check mark.